# Is it compulsory to restart IIS WebApp when Oracle 11g stored procedure are updated?

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle11g, odp.net, odac

I've got an ASP.NET webapp, which uses Oracle 11g stored procedures, through ODAC (Oracle .NET data provider)

I realized that updating the stored procedures seems more than often to break the website, which has to be restarted, so as to work again.

Did anyone experience this strong coupling between .NET and Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

If the code does not need to change when the stored procedure changes, then you don't have to restart IIS.

The calls will still be made through the SP interface as they were.

Comment: Right, that's what's expected, and what I experienced with all the DB engine I worked with. _However_ this particular 11g provider seems to present an issue regarding this use case.

Comment: @Vinzz - How so? Why didn't you post the details of the issue in your question, instead of asking a general question?

Comment: General question so as to know if it's a known issue, but I'll work up a POC, and who knows, I may spot my error (if it's mine) doing so.